# .NET Core 1.0 to 2.0 compilation performance problems

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

We have migrated our ASP.NET Core 1.0 application targeting the .NET Core framework, to Core 2.0. We are seeing around 2x compilation time increase or more after the migration. Every project is different, but are there any special 'gotchas' that we may have done wrong?

**Update**

We are running on .Net Core framework, on Windows Server 2012R2

Comment: Are you using the full framework ? If not, this happen in Windows, Linux or macOs ?

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5918

Comment: Thanks for fast response :) I updated the environment information, so .NET Core framework on Windows

Comment: I went through the issue 5918. It was a bit unclear to me whether the problem exists on all OS:s or not, since some were running similar tests on Windows and it seemed to be quite fast. There were also some cases where a build took a minute, but then after some change it went down to a few seconds.